# Avoiding a possible concurrency issue with a LIST being returned

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, concurrency

Here is the sequence that bother me begging a standard remedy for a concurrency issue

1. Create a list object (lst)
2. Initiate multple threads (Updater Threads)
3. Send that lst to each Updater Threads to update (add) it.
4. Wait for some defined time (t1) to let the Updater threads to proceed with updates.
5. After t1 time expired, return lst to another application (Consumer-App) that isn't in our control.
6. When return it, Updater Threads may be still updating the lst.
7. Consumer-App doesn't know whether the list is still being updating in the background by the Updater Threads.
8. Consumer-App do list operations (add/remove) on lst.

Problem : This will lead to concurrency issue.

How to tackle this?

How to stop updating threads after t1 effectively? Or is there any standard way to deal on this? Will the `synchronizedList (Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList()))` help in this?

**Edit :** 
I'm aware of the CopyOnWriteArrayList also. But I'm focusing on the simple ArrayList on this

Comment: That is far away from being sufficient. First you should think about how to manage the concurrent access *before* t1. If you have a working solution for that problem, the other will come naturally.

Comment: So, do you mean after I return it I don't need to worry if I update it thread safe way (eg : as a synchronized way?). But I'm doubting it. Because API says "it is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it:" [ref:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)]

Comment: Forget about `synchronizedList`. As said, it’s insufficient. You need manual access control. And once you have implemented some kind of manual control, it’s quite easy to add a “are we beyond t1” condition to it that’ll deny the access to the list from the updater threads. Explaining how to do that is too broad. You can’t learn concurrent programming by reading the API documentation; you need to understand the fundamental principles first. I recommend reading “Java Concurrency in Practice” by Brian Goetz, Joshua Bloch, Doug Lea et al

Comment: Yes I understood. That is why I thought to share my doubt with the SOF friends without stopping from API. Thank you for the recommended reading and suggestion Holger. I'll try them out.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a executor service to create and terminate threads, along with a CopyOnWriteArrayList that address concurrency.

```
 private CopyOnWriteArrayList<someObject> someArrayList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<someObject>();
```

...

```
 class NodeStatusThread implements Runnable {

        private ExecutorService UpdaterThreadExecutor = null;
        private int numThrd = 20; //threads 
        private int timeout = 10; // ten-seconds 

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i=0;i<numThrd; i++ ) {
                UpdaterThreadExecutor.execute(new UpdaterThread());
            }
            UpdaterThreadExecutor.shutdown();


            try{
                //Wait for thread completion
                if(!UpdaterThreadExecutor.awaitTermination(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)){  //return false is timeout is surpassed
                    UpdaterThreadExecutor.shutdownNow(); //forces thread termination
                }
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                UpdaterThreadExecutor.shutdownNow();
            }

        }

}
```

...

```
 class UpdaterThread implements Runnable { 

    @Override
    public void run() {
        omeArrayList.add(someObject);

        someArrayList.remove(someObject);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> 4 - Wait for some defined time (t1) to let the Updater threads to proceed with updates.

This is where your design is wrong. You can never be sure every thread has finished updating the list.

You should use a sync mechanism, to allow your consumer thread wait till each one of the producers finishes.

Use [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) or [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Mister Smith. But I'd like to note that I mentioned "to proceed with the update" not "to finish the update". I know that it is not sure that the threads are finished. If I assume that it is finished, I don't worry about the concurrency issue occurred when Consumer-App do list operations on it (Please check latter points also like 6th one as well).