# ConcurrentModificationException Issue When Running Two Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, concurrency, network-programming

So, I am currently working on a server that has support for multie clients, I have one thread that checks if any sockets have connected to the given port and then adds them to an arraylist that the other thread uses to update everything I need to do with the client (Update Info, Check The DataInputStream, Send Text over server) and so on.

Client Code:

```
public class Loop implements Runnable{

ArrayList<ClientInstance> clientsConnected = new ArrayList<ClientInstance>();

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        checkInputStream();
    }

}

public void checkInputStream() {
    for (ClientInstance s : clientsConnected) {
        s.checkInputStream();
    }
}
```

Server Code:

```
public synchronized void waitForClient() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Waiting for client on port: "
                + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
        Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Client Connected! " + client.getInetAddress());
        loop.getClientsConnected().add(new ClientInstance(client));
        System.out.println("Client added to clients connected! ");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But when I run the server and then connect one client to it it works fine, but when i connect another one it gives me this issue:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are modifying arraylist (i.e. adding element in list in `waitForClient()` method ) and at the same time you are iterating it in `checkInputStream()` method.

As mentioned by @Arjit use [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) instead of `ArrayList`.

Comment: how would i fix this? I have tried making the two methods synchronized, but that does not help.

Comment: create a new Collections.unmodifiableList in method checkInputStream.

Comment: or use CopyOnWriteArrayList - Concurrent Collection classes can be modified avoiding ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: @Naman - Iterator will not work - because it allows only remove method but if you are adding element to it, it will throw ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for informing. Will update the code.

Comment: Thank you, the CopyOnWriteArrayList fixed it.

Comment: @Arjit, you can add your answer, and will ask OP to accept your answer.

Comment: I have added an example of CopyOnWriteArrayList

Comment: @FireRaven101, can you please accept the answer given by Arjit.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` to fix it

```
List<String> myList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();     
myList.add("1");
myList.add("2");
myList.add("3");myList.add("4");myList.add("5");
System.out.println("List Value:"+value);

        Iterator<String> it = myList.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            String value = it.next();                    

            if(value.equals("3")){
                myList.remove("4");
                myList.add("6");
                myList.add("7");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("List Size:"+myList.size());
```

Output :-

```
List Value:1
List Value:2
List Value:3
List Value:4
List Value:5
List Size:6
```

PS:-

1. Concurrent Collection classes can be modified avoiding `ConcurrentModificationException`.
2. In case of `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, iterator doesn’t accomodate the changes in the list and works on the original list.

Answer (score 0):

Although you synchronized for the method `waitForClient` (you are inserting elements here) you are not making lock for the method `checkInputStream`.

You can use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` instead of `ArrayList`. It's already answered in the question ["Avoiding a possible concurrency issue with a LIST being returned"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375205/avoiding-a-possible-concurrency-issue-with-a-list-being-returned)